# Is there a programmatic way to detect if the process can interact with desktop

Tags: windows, winapi, service

I have an executable that can run normally or as service. At the startup it may show an error message if there is an error (using `MessageBox` api). This can cause failure if the application is running as service  but not allowed to interact with desktop.The process may appear to be hanging.   Is there a programmatic way to detect if the application can interact with desktop ? I can then use some other error notification mechanism (log file etc)

Comment: It would make more sense to me to switch behaviour on whether or not you are running as a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> To determine whether a service is running as an interactive service,
>   call the GetProcessWindowStation function to retrieve a handle to the
>   window station, and the GetUserObjectInformation function to test
>   whether the window station has the WSF_VISIBLE attribute.

In .NET you can use [Environment.UserInteractive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userinteractive.aspx)

> The UserInteractive property reports false for a Windows process or a
>   service like IIS that runs without a user interface. If this property
>   is false, do not display modal dialogs or message boxes because there
>   is no graphical user interface for the user to interact with.

Comment: Interesting. But this is .NET stuff, not winapi.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* specify `MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION` when calling `MessageBox()`, which will display the message in the currently active session.

*But*, displaying a message box from within a service is not what you really want.

Services are supposed to run in the background and not interact with users directly. One of their characteristics is that they can (and often do) run even when no user is logged on. In Windows Vista they even run in a totally different session than all other users'. Displaying a MessageBox could result in your services being blocked, because the message was invoked in your service's own session without the user knowing about it.

Writing to some sort of a log file or using windows' EventLog is the prefered method.

Answer (score 1):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683502(VS.85).aspx:

To determine whether a service is running as an interactive service, call the GetProcessWindowStation function to retrieve a handle to the window station, and the GetUserObjectInformation function to test whether the window station has the WSF_VISIBLE attribute.